# Change orientation of diagonal of correlation plot using ggcorrplot package

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I am trying to use the ggcorrplot package in R to make a correlation matrix. However, the diagonal in the resulting plot is different than the input correlation matrix.

For example, here is a basic plot using the package:

```
library(ggcorrplot)
data(mtcars)
corr.mat <- cor(mtcars[, c("mpg", "disp", "hp", "drat", "wt", "carb")])
ggcorrplot(corr.mat)
```

This plot has a diagonal going up the matrix from left to right. Instead, I want the resulting plot to look exactly like the correlation matrix that I used as an input:

```
print(corr.mat)
```

That is, the correlation for the `mpg` variable should be at position [1,1] in the matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it by reversing the rows or columns of `corr.mat`:

```
ggcorrplot(corr.mat[,6:1])
```

gives

[image]